# "remediate an issue" vs "remedy an issue"

Tags: difference

Are the phrases "remediate an issue" and "remedy an issue" both correct, and are they synonymous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on what  you’re talking about, and to whom.

- Until very recently *issue*, in the sense you probably intend, meant specifically a question to be resolved, or (only slightly more broadly) a problem to be discussed. It is only in the last twenty-five or thirty years that it has come to mean a problem of any sort in any context—“I have issues with my mother”, “We have issues with our hard drives”—and that sort of use still has a sort of slangy pop-intelligentsia feel. In any case, *issues* are not remedied but debated—or whined about.
- *Remediate* is an old adjective which died out in the 17th century (except occasionally in medical contexts) but was revived as a verb in the 1930s in laws involving industrial pollution, with the fairly narrow sense of “apply a remedy” to soil polluted by industrial waste. That sense has since been extended to efforts to undo or repair the ill effects of any sort of pollution, and still the dominant use and context. From the late 1950s the verb spread into sociological uses, particularly in studies of education and poverty policy, where it again denotes actions to undo deleterious effects.

  The word has begun to creep into other environments, but I advise you not to  use *remediate* unless

  - You’re talking about public policy respecting industrial pollution or social policy, **and**
  - You're talking about repairing damage, not averting it, **and**
  - You want to sound like a stuffy academic or a  pompous and soulless bureaucrat.

I think what you probably want is to *fix a problem*. If that's what you mean, and you're not at a cocktail party or in a conference at the EPA, say that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! How about using *remedy*?

Comment: Remediate has also started gaining traction in software security, when talking about vulnerabilities. A vulnerability can be either "fixed" or "mitigated" as part of the remediation process. I'm not sure it's intended to mean the same thing as remedied or fixed, but it probably falls under jargon and not standard English.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt *Remedy*'s a bit *too* literary. If you want something less colloquial than *fix* I'd go with *solve* -- or *address* if you're still in How-we-gonna-fix-this-guys mode.